# Creating WebServer ip:port on esp8266 module

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, web-server

I creating Clever House with wifi. For this I'm using ESP8266 as module connected to Arduino. They communicate with SoftwareSerial. And there's a problem with global webserver on ESP8266. That I think to do it I must do this:

1.Create Webserver on another port(Neither 80 nor 443) Or Host will be in this model: https://ip:port/

2.Open port forwarding for port.

3.Almost done.

So how can I do it with AT commands?

Comment: http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-esp8266-web-server/

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this is not solvution of my problem. I want to start webserver and its url should be for example 192.168.0.102:5000 -> ip:port

Comment: `AT+CIPSERVER=1,5000`. IP is IP of the esp8266, reserve it on router or use the AT command to set static IP

Comment: what exactly is step number three?

Comment: Nothing :) step 3 is nothing

Comment: THANKS!! It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Juraj mentioned, [martyncurrey.com/arduino-esp8266-web-server](https://martyncurrey.com/arduino-esp8266-web-server) , I need to start server with command: `AT+CIPSERVER=1,5000`, IP is IP of the esp8266 and reserve it on router or use the AT command to set static IP.